# error 415 posting Json file to cloudant public database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, cloudant

I'm trying to send a simple json object to a cloudant database, but I keep getting an error. I set the permissions for the cloudant database to allow read, write and replicate. 
I've already tried rewriting the ajax post to put, I added a header that didn't solve the error, but I keep getting the error, and can't seem to find the cause.

The exact error is:

```
POST https://birdoftravel.cloudant.com/questions/_all_docs/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
send @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4
saveQuestionToDB @ saveQuestion.js:54
(anonymous) @ saveQuestion.js:77
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
```

```js
function QuestionObject(q, o, a){
    this.question = q;
    this.options = o;
    this.answer = a;
    
}


function createQuestion(){
    
    var q = $('#question').val();
    console.log("question: "+q);
    var o = $('#options').val().split(',');
    
    var a = $('#answer').val();
    
    var question = new QuestionObject(q,o,a);
    
    var jsonQ = JSON.stringify(question);
    
    console.log("json string"+jsonQ);
    
    $('#question').val("");
    $('#options').val("");
    $('#answer').val("");
    
    return jsonQ;
  
}

function saveQuestionToDB(){
    var urlDB = 'https://birdoftravel.cloudant.com/questions/_all_docs/';
    var data = createQuestion();
    console.log("data :"+data);
    
   /* $.ajax({
        
        url: urlDB,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            alert('The question was posted!');
        },
        
        error: function(err){
            console.log("error: "+err+" question not posted: "+data);
        }
        
    });*/
    
    $.ajax({
  
        type: "POST",
  
        url: urlDB,
  
        data: data,
  
        success: function(d){
            console.log("question was posted!"+d);
            
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log("not posted! "+e);
        },
            
  
        dataType: "application/json",
        

    });
}

$('#btn').click(function(e){
    saveQuestionToDB();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        

    

       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="quizStyle.css">
        <script
                src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  
                integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  
                crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        
        <title>Add a new quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <h2>Enter a new quiz</h2>
        
            <form id="newQuizForm">
        
                Insert question:<br>
                <input type="text" id="question"><br>
                Insert optional answers seperated by ;<br>
                <input type="text" id="options"><br>
                Insert correct answer:<br>
                <input type="text" id="answer"><br>
                <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Save question">
        
            </form>
        
       
        <script src="saveQuestion.js"></script>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the request to the wrong API endpoint. Send a `POST` request to `https://birdoftravel.cloudant.com/questions` (`https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE`) and the insert operation should succeed. Refer to https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#create for details.

The endpoint you were using `https://birdoftravel.cloudant.com/questions/_all_docs` lists all documents in a database: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/database.html#get-documents

The following modified version of your javascript code worked for me. Note the changes:

- URL
- Authorization header
- Content-Type header

  ```
  function saveQuestionToDB(){
      var urlDB = 'https://<cloudant-user-name>.cloudant.com/questions';
      var data = createQuestion();
      console.log("data :"+data);

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('<cloudant-user-name>' + ":" + '<cloudant-password>));
          },
          url: urlDB,          
          data: data,
          success: function(d){
              console.log("question was posted!"+ JSON.stringify(d));                  
          },
          error: function(j,t,s){
              console.log("not posted! "+ JSON.stringify(j));
              console.log("not posted! "+ JSON.stringify(t));
              console.log("not posted! "+ JSON.stringify(s));
          },
          contentType: "application/json"
      });
  }
  ```

Since you are running this in a browser you need to enable CORS otherwise your request will fail: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cors.html#cors

Comment: Even when changed to that, it keeps giving the same 415 error. 
I also tried sending a post with postman, and I get the same error.

{
  "error": "bad_content_type",
  "reason": "Content-Type must be application/json"
}

Sending a get works though, I really don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: I send along an extra parameter for content type to be json, and now it's giving an error regarding the utf-8 of json.

Comment: See updates in my original response. To enable CORS in Cloudant, open the **Account** tab and select **CORS**.